# ActiveRecord Pattern and caching?

Tags: php, design-patterns

I have in one project classes organized with ActivePattern (example : myObject->Load()) but now we need to implement some caching and caching is problematic.

To make it simples, the Load() method in every object call the DAL my giving the $this reference and the DAL fill up the object that all values. It works. But when we add some caching the object unserialized is a "new" object and the DAL cannot sent it back to the object because we have a reference to the object that need to be loaded. The only work around is to put the cache code inside the Load() of each object and to loop all properties from the caching object to Get the value and to Set it back to the real object.

Is there a better way to use caching with ActiveRecord Pattern?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand - what is it that you want to cache? Can you give a code example of what you do at the moment?

Comment: I want to cache $myObject. If I do $myObject->Load(), once loaded from the database I can easily cache it because in the Load() I have passed to the DAL the myObject reference and it has loaded it. I can than save it to the cache (serialize($this)). The problem is when it's the time to Load() later... it finds that it's in the cache, it return a new object unserialized but I am in the object and I can't do $this = $objectUnserializedFromCache; You get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly from your comment your problem is replacing this. What I would do is create a static "fetch" method on the active record class that would check cache, return if available, and if not return a new instance of the class. This will get you around having to replace this, and the only thing you have to change is the way you are loading the active record class.